# hide closed Hg branches in TeamCity

Tags: mercurial, branch, teamcity

I've been using TeamCity to build all of my named branches (in Mercurial). It works well. However, TeamCity continues to show the branches after they have been closed for up to seven days past the last commit time to that branch. I would like to hide closed branches, aka, not show them in the TeamCity list. Does anyone know how to hide closed branches in TeamCity? I'm currently using TeamCity v8.1.2.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [TeamCity documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Clean-Up) you can set up the cleanup defaults from the following menus:

*Administration* | *Project-related Settings* | *Build History Clean-up* page, *Configure clean-up* rules section.

Comment: I can see where to adjust the times and build counts there, but I don't see anything related to branch status.

Comment: Experiment - maybe set it to clean up old branches daily instead of weekly. Did you have any joy in the end?